# "Reload file?" error in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, file-access

I'm using codeblocks to as my IDE for C++ and every 10mins or so I get the following
error message:

"Reload File? File c:...node.cpp is modified outside the IDE. Do you want to reload 
it? (you will lose andy unsaved work)" Yes/No/All/Cancel

If I click yes by mistake sometimes I lose the last couple of minutes of work. If I
click no then everything remains ok.

So I downloaded "Process Monitor" to find out what program was accessing my cpp file
and it tells me that SVCHost may be the culprit.

As far as I'm aware SVCHost is responsible for all sorts of things. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to stop receiving this error message?

N.B. This error message didn't appear for the first month or so that I used codeblocks,
but I have no idea what I've done that might have caused the problem.

[Screenshot][http://i44.tinypic.com/sgk3sx.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and I resolved it by removing a tick in front of "check for externally modified files" in

> Settings -> Environment -> General settings

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that `svchost` is a generic process name that is used by a multitude of different services. I think the reason was to prevent a lot of processes for every tiny little service that might want to do something - a group of them will share a single `svchost` process.

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) can be used to figure out what services are being performed by a specific `svchost` process by finding the process ID (1296 in your JPEG file) and double-clicking on the entry.

Then, in the properties dialog that appears, choose the services tab and it will show you the particular services using that process.

If you don't want to (or can't) install Process Explorer, you can use the command-line:

```
tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eg svchost.exe"
```

to get a list of all the services in each process.